# An Instance of Needing Double JSON.parse() for Text Response

Tags: javascript, json

This isn't so much a problem as a solution I found, and have no idea how it's working. I was making a `fetch` call and receiving a text response that I needed to convert to workable JSON.

```
"[{\"Rank\":1,\"FISHERMAN_PHONENAME\":\"James Elam\"...}]"
```

One `JSON.parse` knocked off the end double quotes and the slashes, but it still wasn't coming back as the json array of objects I needed so I ended up doing this:

```
if (response.ok) {
  const payload = await response.text();
  data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(payload));
}
```

That did the trick, but I have no idea why it needed a double parse to make it happen. Any insight would be awesome.

Comment: If you strip off the leading and trailing double quotes, so that all you have is `[{\"Rank\":1,\"FISHERMAN_PHONENAME\":\"James Elam\"...}]`, does one `JSON.parse` do the trick?

Comment: @Snake14: `\"` is not a valid character sequence in JSON at that position.

Comment: @FelixKling good call.  I guess having the inner double quotes escaped would be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I have no idea why it needed a double parse to make it happen.

Because the data was double encoded as JSON. JSON would simply be

```
{"Rank":1,"FISHERMAN_PHONENAME":"James Elam"...}
```

While

```
"[{\"Rank\":1,\"FISHERMAN_PHONENAME\":\"James Elam\"...}]"
```

is also valid JSON, in this case it's a (JSON) string that contains other JSON data.

Here is a simply example that demonstrates double encoding:

```js
console.log('Once', JSON.stringify({foo: 42}));
console.log('Twice', JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify({foo: 42})));
```

Note how the first one does not include leading and trailing quotes.

---

**You should fix the process that generates the JSON to only encode it once.**