# How to model a json object with dynamic keys in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Our backend is returning most string data as json object strings where each key represents a language code that may or may not exist on a particular database record. For example, it will come down as:

```
{
 "id": "4788fb8d-fb63-4189-a9e8-68624180852e",
 "description": "{\"en\":\"description of co\",\"es\":\"descripción de la co\"}", "options": "[{}]"
}
```

Or:

```
{
    "id": "4788fb8d-fb63-4189-a9e8-68624180852e",
    "description": "{\"en\":\"description of company\"}",
    "options": [{"en":"english text"},{"en":"english text","es":"spanish text"},{"en":""}]
}
etc..
```

What is an appropriate way to represent this type across our whole web app so all our objects can be safely worked with? I'm sure this is probably a bit naive:

```
  interface StringType {
    en: string | undefined;
    es: string | undefined;
    de: string | undefined;

  }
```

```
interface Customer {
   id: string; 
   description: StringType;
   options: StringType[]; //
}
```

And how would I narrow the keys to only be our supported language codes, for example 'en' or 'es' or 'de' instead of any string?

**Update**: Someone asked if my responses are actually doubly encoded like this. Here is an example of an actual response via the network tab. I have a helper fn that maps over each key of each response to see if its value is json and if so I JSON.parse it.

actual response:

```
[{
"id": "bc07c211-5b09-4e4b-b139-75c53a238d83",
"name": "{\"en\":\"Truck\"}"
},
{
"id": "a003b497-2216-4171-ab0e-d458f7025a73",
"name": "{\"en\":\"Boat\",\"es\":\"boet\"}"
}]
```

Note: When sending data up, we `JSON.stringify` each string that needs to support multiple languages, but only their default language is required - so if they don't choose a non-default language, only one key will be sent.

Comment: Are your properties *really* doubly encoded like that as opposed to just [plain old JSON like this](https://tsplay.dev/WJVY5W)? If so, that's very unfortunate and you should mention that here explicitly.  If not, then please [edit] your code to be a [mre].

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by doubly encoded but what I posted is exactly how they come across the network, and I have a helper fn that parses each key's value in a response that appears to be json using ```json.parse()``` resulting in an object.   eg: a name field's value would be: ```"{\"en\":\"Hello\"}"```
And after parsing would be: ```{en: 'Hello'}```

Is that what you mean? Please let me know and I'll update question.

Comment: I'll just give you an exact response from the network tab: 

```[{"id": "1238f6da-edb8-4c1a-a846-efdc6544423a4c","name": "{\"en\":\"Truck\"}"},{"id": "ed067583-8981-480f-88ec-1abb21158fc1","name": "{\"en\":\"Boat\",\"es\":\"boet\"}"}]```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean, and it's **really bad practice** for a back end to work that way. Clients shouldn't have to JSON-parse the results of JSON-parsing the back end response.  See [this q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53329918/2887218) for example. There's no good way to strongly type JSON strings in Typescript and you shouldn't have to. Someone should make the back end send `[{ "id": "bc07c211-5b09-4e4b-b139-75c53a238d83", "name": { "en": "Truck" } }, { "id": "a003b497-2216-4171-ab0e-d458f7025a73", "name": { "en": "Boat", "es": "boet" } }]` instead and then it could be strongly typed.

Comment: Thank you, it's been a source of frustration doing UI this way. I'll have to read up and find out why he designed it that way. Our architect is quite strong technically, so I'm curious. I'll have to find out why and what to do about it. I would love to have better typing. I looked up double encoded json and found lodash lib that might help.

Comment: If that's what you're dealing with, I can imagine using branded string types to try to mark the string as saying "when you `JSON.parse()` this the result is a `StringType`", where `StringType` looks like `Partial<Record<Langs, string>>`, as shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/wgvevW).  Not sure if this meets your needs or fully addresses the question though.  Especially the idea that maybe you get a string which represents the default language, or *maybe* you get a json-encoded string representing a `StringType`.  You shouldn't have to *detect* if a string is json-encoded or not! 

Comment: ha, thanks for the playground. I'll have to digest that idea but Partial<Record<Langs, string>> looks promising. Yes, some strings are just normal strings but I know that up front. Normal = the ones that don't represent front end device content (vs. admin data). So it's a case by case basis that we decide up front and it requires logic to handle it, I'm just not sure how a senior FE dev would deal with it. Maybe I can brand them

Comment: Do you want me to write up my playground link suggestion as an answer?  Or would that fail to address the question in some way?

Comment: yes, I think it would be very helpful and relevant. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In what follows I will assume that the response from the back end is a string of the following form:

```
console.log(rawResponseString)
/* '[
  {"id":"abc","name":"{\"en\":\"Truck\"}"},
  {"id":"def","name":"{\"en\":\"Boat\",\"es\":\"boet\"}"}
]' */
```

which means, when that is JSON-decoded on the client end, it becomes a JavaScript object of the following form:

```
const response = JSON.parse(rawResponseString);
console.log(response);
/* [{
     "id": "abc",
     "name": "{\"en\":\"Truck\"}" 
   }, {
     "id": "def",
     "name": "{\"en\":\"Boat\",\"es\":\"boet\"}"
   }] */
```

which means that the `name` property of the array elements are *strings*, not objects.  In order to proceed from here you need to JSON-decode these strings *again* in order to get the objects you care about:

```
const parsedAgain = response.map(
  ({ id, name }) => ({ id, name: JSON.parse(name) })
);
console.log(parsedAgain);
/* [{
  "id": "abc",
  "name": {
    "en": "Truck"
  }
}, {
  "id": "def",
  "name": {
    "en": "Boat",
    "es": "boet"
  }
}]  */
```

**This is almost certainly bad practice.  The back end should be changed so that it encodes the whole response as a single JSON object without encoding pieces multiple times.** For now I will just assume this is how it is, but it shouldn't be this way.

---

There's a general situation that the TypeScript compiler can't do much to strongly type JSON-strings, especially strings that are only known at runtime (say, from a server response).  So [the `JSON.parse()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is [declared in TypeScript's library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/157753520520fd0936bff280de30af56e15f94ee/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1135) to return [the intentionally loose `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  Even if you knew the JSON string as a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) at compile time, it would be a huge undertaking to try to make the *compiler* parse it as JSON, and it's mostly not worth it to try.  `JSON.parse()` returns a value of type `any`, and then the client code can just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the value is of the expected type, or write [type guarding](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) code to verify that it's of the expected type.

I think most of the time clients just use a type assertion or the equivalent (for `any` you can just assign the value to a variable [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type you want and the compiler won't tell), and assume things will be as expected.

---

So, if the back end returned a singly-encoded string, the expected type for your response could be something like this:

```
type Langs = "en" | "es" | "de"; // as many as you want
interface StringType extends Partial<Record<Langs, string>> { }

declare function getResponse(): Array<{ id: string, name: StringType }>;
const r = getResponse();
```

There `StringType` is built using [the `Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) and [the `Record<K, V>` utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type), and is equivalent to

```
interface StringType {
  en?: string;
  es?: string;
  de?: string;
}
```

where each of the keys from the `Langs` [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) represent [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) of type `string`.

That would let you do this:

```
r.forEach(x => {
  console.log(
    x.id,
    (x.name.en ?? "unknown").toUpperCase(),
    (x.name.es ?? "desconocido").toUpperCase()
  );
})
// "abc",  "TRUCK",  "DESCONOCIDO" 
// "def",  "BOAT",  "BOET"
```

So that might answer your original typing question, *if* the back end were returning normal things.

---

But given that you need to re-parse the JSON strings, you'll end up with just `string`s for the `name` properties and you'll have to parse those and reassert:

```
declare function getResponse(): Array<{ id: string, name: string }>;
const r = getResponse();
const val = r.map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name: JSON.parse(name) }))
// const val: { id: string; name: any; }[] // <-- any in there
const parsedAgain: Array<{id: string, name: StringType}> = val; // ‍♂️
```

If you want, you could try to tell the compiler that the result of `getResponse()` will have `name` properties of a special kind of `string` that becomes `StringType` when parsed, possibly by using [branded primitives](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal), and then [merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) another call signature for `JSON.parse()` which handles it:

```
type EncodedStringType = string & { __myStringType: true };
interface JSON {
  parse(str: EncodedStringType): StringType;
}
declare function getResponse(): Array<{ id: string, name: EncodedStringType }>;

const r = getResponse();
const val = r.map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name: JSON.parse(name) }));
// const val: { id: string; name: StringType; }[] // <-- it knows now
const parsedAgain: Array<{ id: string, name: StringType }> = val; //
```

That behaves a little better.  None of these approaches will handle the situation where the back end returns something unexpected, which is a fundamental limitation of `JSON.parse()`, and no matter what you do the code will end up parsing JSON at least once.  If I *had* to parse JSON multiple times, I'd probably want to use branded types so that at least I only need to assert in one place per response.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAMgQwHYHMDOMC8MBEUk4wA+uUahJOAJlDgNwwD0jMCGAtsmKxmAPYBXGAHdkIYAEskIKACcAZggDGsAMohZUlABVIsKAA8ZSKhgAKCWSAkIANgB4ASlCV9ZVe4lRoANDDQaWgB8QTAA3jAAvsCgejAAokiuNFTqmqi60Fj+gagwAGThMAD6xexgaVqZUABcMBoCsJF0ktJyiiowAFKqAPIAcuHAMDAQlmhQABQBsnWJyVCpuTp6AJR1lRl6LdHA8gJJ1nxIMChQIM5oEMcTk+swAIKysghg9hESVHUzWn5ICOxagkknwUpsVllIqEwsMYK4kAEYC9hJdrgioODsgADADasJGYQAOjhPsSasSEAAjJTEnzE-6AsnEomE4n4VlM1k4bSyARKADWHJwkWJkR8+PCxNJOHJ1Cg8lp9IBUCZOBZbKQQvJXIAQnwECAhXSuWQtULKXxzkKRcLYQBdLEtEbwtB8WxQAB0tj4KEmyNRNwxy1WsMYACoYHiRgSSVQZTgqUocD4cAzaDU1RrVTy+YLhcLxdHwrH4zR5MnU8r40S8JqZcS9QbFXg0KqLVb89ERnaYGHGLCXSBRuNFtkegMPWNZLd-WQ0RNwSGRsw4Tch1OJl9WEhuIA+DcA7LuAWAJAEJkgHg-2Gyc4CWQnDeLHYxfaHCTHHgTKwPFAIKR3OpPF5vB8W4-KgfzKhsyzVFE0IDmuSJ-s8rzvDAnzfMsYGAmh6QoNB2RnBcc6BncTqrgiQ4AG52NksgepwECTJMQEYU0qxYKEjEoVQzF1OO-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)